# A dynamic shop command (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, object, discord.js

I have been making a shop command and wondering if I could make it dynamic. So what we do here is make an items object then a lot of items in it. Each item has its own object with its key. For every item, I want to add an embed field with the name as the item and the value as the item's key. Is there anyway to do that?

Code:

```
const items = {
    hoodie: {
        key: 'hoodie'
    },
    shoe: {
        key: 'shoe'
    }
}
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('items')

// add embed fields

message.channel.send(embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate through the items object and add that to the embed.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const items = {
    hoodie: {
        key: 'hoodie'
    },
    shoe: {
        key: 'shoe'
    }
};

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('items');

Object.Keys(items).forEach(itemName => {
    embed.addField(itemName, items[itemName].key)
})

message.channel.send(embed);
```

Also, I would recommend you to use an array for storing the items:

```
const item = [
    {
        name: 'hoodie',
        key: 'This is a hoodie!'
    },
    {
        name: 'shoe',
        key: 'This is a shoe!'
    }
];
```